# Leaflet: How to use `getLatLngs` on a geoJSON polyline?

Tags: maps, leaflet, mapbox, geojson, turfjs

I create a geoJSON polyline object called `bezier` using [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_bezier.html) like this:

```
var linestring = turf.linestring(
        [[121.465, 31.233], [121.500634, 31.233499], [121.588107, 31.190172], [121.501545, 31.207394], [121.337514, 31.196079]]
        , {
            "stroke": "#25561F",
            "stroke-width": 5
        });

var bezier = turf.bezier(linestring, 50000, 0.85);

bezier.properties = {
    "stroke": "#6BC65F",
    "stroke-width": 5,
    "description": "Bezier line from polyline"
}

L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(bezier).addTo(map);
```

Then, I used `bezier.geometry.coordinates` to access its point array.. But what I really need is the array of `LatLng` object (because the `L.animatedMarker` in [this plugin](https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker#how-can-i-use-it) needs latlngs), I was wondering whether there is a way to extract the `LatLng` array like what `getLatLngs` method did on leaflet object.

Comment: What is a `GeoJSON polyline`? There is no such thing. Do you mean a GeoJSON LineString feature? Or do you mean a `L.Polyline` object created from a GeoJSON LineString feature through a `L.GeoJSON` layer? You're also talking about a "leaflet object". Your question is very confusing, at least to me. Why not supply some code or better yet an JSfiddle or Plunker which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @iH8 sorry for the confusion.. The codes to create GeoJSON `bezier` is added.. Is there an easier way to use `getLatLngs` on `bezier`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first need to get a reference to the actual layer from the layer you've added it to, in this instance that would be your L.mapbox.featureLayer. Once you've got that, you can just use the `getLatLngs` method. You can do this in multiple ways:

Use the `layeradd` event, the cleanest way:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

featureLayer.on('layeradd', function (e) {
    var latLngs = e.layer.getLatLngs();
})

var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(bezier).addTo(map);
```

If you're only going to insert one layer like you're doing now you could also fetch it directly from the layers object contained in the featurelayer:

```
var key = Object.keys(featureLayer._layers)[0];
var latLngs = featureLayer._layers[key].getLatLngs();
```

Or if you've got multiple layers in your featureLayer and don't want to use events you can loop over the featureLayer and grab it from there:

```
featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    var latLngs = layer.getLatLngs();
});
```